# How can I edit label text in ggplot2?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I've built a function that utilizes ggplot2 to create a bar chart for a given style of summary table, but there are a few changes I'd like to make that I haven't quite figured out. Here's what the function looks like:

```
bar_chart_dist <- function(df, x_var, y_var, title) {
  title_in_fun <- title
  p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = df[,x_var], y = df[,y_var])) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="#005a8c") + 
  geom_text(aes_string(label= y_var, vjust = -0.2)) +
  xlab("") + ylab(y_var) + my_theme() + 
  ggtitle(title_in_fun) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100))
  return(p)
}
```

The `my_theme` function edits the font family to Open Sans and changes the color to grey, among other things.

The data frames I am using with this function are each three variables long -- topic (this name changes with each given dataframe), n (number of observations) and percent_of_population (pre-calculated percent of total population in a given group). I'm using topic as my `x_var` and percent_of_population as my `y_var`.

There are a few things here I haven't gotten to work:

1) I'd like the y-axis to be labeled with a percent sign (%) and to span 0% to 100%. I've tried to edit the `scale_y_continuous argument` to be:
    `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent, limits=c(0,100))`
but that changes the scale such that my upper boundary is 10,000%.

2) I'd like to change the font color, size, and family in the geom_text argument, as well as add a % sign to the label. The family I'd like to use is Open Sans, but it doesn't seem to recognize that. When I set `size = 4`, a legend is created, which does not seem to happen in the examples I've looked at.

Any help you guys can provide is very much appreciated. I'm not sure what's not working because this is wrapped in a function, and what's not working because it's the wrong approach. [Here's what the plot looks like in current state:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnWL3.png)

Comment: limits = `c(0, 1)` will make your upper boundary 100%. The help for `?geom_text` shows that it understands `family = "Open Sans"` just like `theme` functions.

Comment: ggplot (and most mathematics) equates a value of `1` as `100%`. If you have a value of data that is say, `98`, but you want it plotted as `98%` then you should divide your data values by 100.

Comment: This question will get a lot more concrete if you [make your example reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). How are you using Open Sans in your theme? Are you already using the `extrafont` package?

Comment: @Gregor I was hesitant to update the data values, but just did and axis labeling is working perfectly now. Also tried doing `family = "OpenSans"`, and got it working -- thanks for your help!

Comment: For adding the percent signs to `geom_text`, I think the easiest way would be to again update your data. Create a new column `df$label = paste0(df[yvar], "%")`, then you can just set `aes(label = label)` for `geom_text`. It's possible to do the pasting inside `aes()`, but with `aes_string()` things get messy.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks again for your help.